# Installing jfrog insights

Tags: jfrog-insights

I am trying to install jfrog insights by following their official documentation https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Insight#InstallingInsight-ManualDockerComposeInstallation

while executing the command step 3: `./config.sh`
I got the error

> Error: [ERROR] YQ_PATH is not set, the script requires a $YQ_PATH/yq to work with system.yaml

Please someone help me to fix

Answer (score 0):

[YQ](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) is a portable YAML processor.  You can either install it or point it to the `<installer_home>/third-party/yq` folder

*installer_home is where you extracted the docker-compose package

Answer (score 0):

YQ YAML processor is bundled within compose package of JFrog Xray.
Set env variable YQ_PATH to <installer_home>/third-party/yq